# How to read in file containing blank space and punctuation?

Tags: c++, space, punctuation

I have problem reading in the file that contain space ad punctuation. I use `inFile >> letter` to read the char and num. When I read file that is space or punctuation, it stop reading the text file.

Here's the text file I need to read

```
a 31
  12
e 19
i 33
o 41
u 11
, 2
```

**Code:**

```
char letter; 
int num; 

inFile.open(FILENAME.c_str());
  if(inFile.fail())
    cout << "Error..." << endl;
  while (inFile >> letter){
    inFile >> num ;
  }
  inFile.close();
```

*Could anyone tell me how to fix it?*

Thanks

Comment: What here is broken? The program never stores or attempts to output anything, nor did you mention any such behavior.

Comment: it reads fine when there's a, b,c....it stop reading it when there's a space or ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've compiled this code(MSVC2012):

```
char letter; 
int num; 
std::fstream inFile;

inFile.open("1.txt");
if(inFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Error..." << endl;
}
while (inFile >> letter)
{
    inFile >> num ;
    std::cout << letter << " | " << num << std::endl;
}
inFile.close();
```

And get this output:

```
a | 31
1 | 2
e | 19
i | 33
o | 41
u | 11
, | 2
```

If you have another compiler and it stops parsing, you can use std::getline and try use std::stringstream:

```
char letter; 
int num; 
std::fstream inFile;

inFile.open("1.txt");
if(inFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Error..." << endl;
}
while (!inFile.eof())
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(inFile, line);
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    stream >> letter >> num;
    std::cout << letter << " | " << num << std::endl;
}
inFile.close();
```

But you still get the problem if you have a space in the begining of string. To avoid this, you should split string by spaces and parse the parts by stringstream or atoi

Answer (score 0):

Use `getline` instead and parse the text as you see fit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;

    while (cin)
    {
        getline(cin, line);
        string col1 = line.substr(0, 1);
        string col2 = line.substr(2);

        char letter = ' ';
        int  num    = -1;

        if (!col1.empty())
            letter = col1[0];
        if (!col2.empty())
            num = stoi(col2);

        cout << letter << "/" << num << '\n';
    }
}
```